# Flutter RadioListTile Radio(icon) Size

Tags: flutter

After searching and several attempts, I did not find a way to increase the **RadioListTile** Radio(icon) **Size in width, height and thickness**
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListTile instead of RadioListTile for increase size of Radio button as below code

```
ListTile(
      leading: Transform.scale(
        scale: 1.5,
        child: Radio(
          value: false,
          groupValue: 0,
          onChanged: (value) {},
        ),
      ),
      title: Text('RadioListTile'),
    ),
```

Otherwise you have to make custom Radio button as per your requirement

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work with RadioListTile. Even when used with Radio, how can I control the thickness

Comment: Thank you very much, but what about the thickness

Comment: There is no inbuilt property for the thickness, so you have to make your custom radio button

Answer (score 0):

you could use the dense property like this:

```
RadioListTile(
dense: false, // Set to true for a smaller widget
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0, vertical: 8.0), // Increase or decrease the padding as needed
title: Text('RadioListTile'),
value: 1,
groupValue: 1,
onChanged: (value) {},
);
```